# Print message when table is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that is called: `mytable`.

Is there an option to know when the table is scrolled?

assuming I want to print a message: "the table is scrolled", how can I do it please?

```
$('#mytable').scroll(function () {
    alert('The Table Is Scrolled');
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/JJV59/20/)

Comment: `mytable` is a class and id or what is that?

Comment: can we see sample fiddle link or html code ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/JJV59/20/

thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table has a wrapper (that makes the scroll bars to appear) you can do:

```
$('.myTable').parent().scroll(function () {
    alert('The Table Is Scrolled');
});
```

In your JSFIDDLE:

```
$('#tableAppointment').parent().scroll(function () {
    alert('The Table Is Scrolled');
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/W5hLb/)

Comment: @AlonShmiel Good! You must use the scroll handler to the table wrapper (the parent).